# How do I call lock screen Windows without win+l

Tags: windows-10

Can we just run like `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#XX` to call lock screen on Windows 10..?

I need to call it without win+l because my Delphi cannot simulate win logo key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command to lock the screen:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```